# Transparent text on fillable form PDF

Tags: pdf

We've received a PDF from a vendor with fillable forms. When I type my name is the fillable form, I can see a transparent copy of my name behind the text I typed. If I delete my text, the transparent copy remains there until I move to the next fillable field. I've tried this in 2 different versions of Adobe Acrobat and the issue persists. Other fillable form PDFs do not display this issue. The vendor is adamant that the issue is not on their end.

I'd like to see if I can disprove this behavior as the result of anything in our environment.[Sample Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRwqt.jpg)

I've included an example screenshot of what the transparent text looks like

Comment: When you first opened the document, in the Sender Name field, was there any pre-filled text? Or was it completely blank?

Comment: Hi Narzard.....Completely blank. No text visible.

Comment: Your post says you are opening this in Acrobat. If you open it in Reader, does the field name appear? Consider that in Acrobat, you may be in edit mode?

Comment: Hi fred_dot_u......tested in Adobe Reader just now and it's the same behavior. Opened in Reader, fill in my name in the Sender Name field. Verify the transparent copy shows up as well. Remove my typed name and only the transparent copy remains until I move to the next fillable field where it then disappears completely.